# Problem Extending Python(Linking Error )?

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linker

I have installed Python 3k(C:\Python30) and Visual Studio Professional Edition 2008.

I'm studying **[this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C).**

Here is a problem:

```
C:\hello>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 309E-14FB

 Directory of C:\hello

03/21/2009  01:15 AM    <DIR>          .
03/21/2009  01:15 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/21/2009  01:14 AM               481 hellomodule.c
               1 File(s)            481 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  10,640,642,048 bytes free


C:\hello>cl /LD hellomodule.c /Ic:\Python30\include c:\Python30\libs\python30.lib /link/out:hello.
dll
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hellomodule.c
c:\hello\hellomodule.c(26) : warning C4716: 'inithello' : must return a value
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hellomodule.dll
/dll
/implib:hellomodule.lib
/out:hello.dll
hellomodule.obj
c:\Python30\libs\python30.lib
   Creating library hellomodule.lib and object hellomodule.exp
hellomodule.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Py_InitModule referenced in function
_inithello
hello.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

C:\hello>
```

What is the problem? Please, guide me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help. I did a screencast for compiling extensions for a friend. It's with VS2003.  http://pylot.org/compiling_pylot_cpp_extensions.wmv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Python is installed in `c:\python30`, why are you searching for the libraries in `c:\Python24\libs\python30`?

And now that you've changed the question to fix this :-),

I don't think `Py_InitModule` is available any more, you have to use `PyModule_Create` (this may have changed since the early betas of Py3k which is the last time I looked).

Based on your comments, David, I'd suggest you need to avoid the HowTo sites outside of the official Python docs (I suspect they're well out of date). There was a lot of work happening on the extension interface at the 3.0 level and the best place to look is either 
at the [3.0 docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/extending/extending.html) or [3.1 alpha docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/extending/extending.html).

The specific Windows build instructions are [here](http://docs.python.org/3.0/extending/windows.html).

Comment: Cool, It generated hello.dll, Now,How should I import it?(I tried import hello).But is says no module named hello.

Comment: NOTE: I just replaced Py_InitModule by PyModule_Create.Is that fine or do I need anything else.